# React Typed Children with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to react and I am facing an issue accessing the children array.
I have a component like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
    doSomething(): void {
    }
    render() {
        return <span>Test</span>
    }
}
```

The application is:

```
function App() {
    return <MyContainer>
        <MyComponent />
        <br />
        <MyComponent />
        <br />
        <MyComponent />
    </MyContainer>;
}
```

MyContainer is a component made in this way:

```
class MyContainer extends React.Component {
    OnClickHandler() {
        React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, c => {
            // if ([[Check if c is MyComponent]]) {
            //     //c.doSomething();
            // }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.children}
            <br />
            <input type="button" onClick={this.OnClickHandler} value="ClickMe" />
        </React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

How do I Check if a child compoment is of type MyComponent and obtain an instance to it?

Comment: You need to make `OnClickHandler` into an arrow function in order to access `this.props.children`.  Whatever the ultimate goal is, there is probably a better way to achieve it than manipulation of the children.

Comment: I recommend lifting your state up one or two levels and avoid using `React.Children`. It's both hard to read and follow. If you could describe what you're trying to achieve, we might be able help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the ultimate goal is, there is probably a better way to achieve it than manipulation of the children.  This is generally not a good design.

You need to change `OnClickHandler` into an arrow function in order to access `this.props.children`.  Otherwise `this` refers to the local context of the function.

If you log the children you'll see that they are objects with properties `type`, `key`, `ref`, and `props`.  This is different than what typescript thinks they are, which is `ReactNode`.  So the following code will have typescript errors.  But it does properly identify which children are `MyComponent`.

```
OnClickHandler = () => {
  console.log(this.props.children)
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
      if (child?.type === MyComponent) {
        console.log("yes");
      } else {
        console.log("no")
      }
    });
}
```

This isn't going to do what you want though, because these `child` objects do not have a `doSomething()` property.

It makes much more sense to design this in a way that the components get a `didClick` property.

Comment: Can I cast or transform in some way the child in the foreach into an instance of MyComponent?

Comment: Sorry, I am actually newbe, it does not compile: "TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactNodeArray | ReactPortal'.
  Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'."

Why?